# Using Powershell to Download an .EXE File

Tags: powershell

I am trying to silently download an installer from https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-2017-downloads.html through powershell. It seems like something is blocking my access on the server side, or I am taking the wrong steps to download this file. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note: the .exe link does not work unless you hit the downloads.html page first in a browser

CODE:

```
$outfile = .\PATH\TO\MYFILE
$url = @("https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-2017-downloads.html","http://trials3.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/APRO/Acrobat_HelpX/win32/Acrobat_2017_Web_WWMUI.exe")

Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url[0]
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url[1] -OutFile $outfile
```

I expect the file to download, but I receive download errors from the server.

ERRORS:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Access Denied
>   You don't have permission to access "http://trials3.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/APRO/Acrobat_HelpX/win32/Acrobat_2017_Web_WWMUI.exe" on this server.
>
> Reference #18.6ef0fea5.1512177436.8f90778
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url[1]
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Yeah, That part I get. Something with it 'authenticates'. kinda. The download URL is from this site: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-2017-downloads.html

Comment: So the download URL can be found on the download buttons, if you load up the downloads.html, you'll be able to click dirrectly on the trials3.adobe.com link

Comment: it's looking like all roads point to https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-2017-downloads.html ,but I suppose this would work if I could find a local server without authentication to host it on.

Comment: The website might be restricting access to certain types of clients, like web browsers. I tried using `curl` under Linux and saw the same error. So it's not a PowerShell issue *per se*.

Comment: Yep, that makes it seem like it's an issue on the adobe server side.  I'll see if there's some type of work around. Thank you for the confirmation.